# storing html form values in xml file

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

i have entered 15 characters in 'item_detail'(data.html) field but i want to store just 10 characters in 'itemdetail' element in xml file(item.xml) how can i do that?

data.html----

```
 <form>
     <p>Id:<input type="text" name= "id" size="10" /> </p>
     <p>Item Detail:<textarea name="item_detail" rows="3" cols="50" ></textarea></p>
     <input name="submit" type = "button" onClick = "getData('data.php','info', id.value, ,item_detail.value)" value = "Add Item" />

</form>    

 <div id="info"> </div>
```

data.js-------

```
var xhr = createRequest();
function getData(dataSource, divID, id,itemd) {
if(xhr) {
var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
var requestbody ="idd="+encodeURIComponent(id)+"&itd="+encodeURIComponent(itemd);
xhr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
obj.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
} // end if
} // end anonymous call-back function
xhr.send(requestbody);
} // end if
} // end function getData()
```

data.php file-----------

```
$id= $_POST["idd"];
$item_detail= $_POST["itd"];


            $xml = new DomDocument();
            $xml->load("item.xml");
            $xml->formatOutput = true;   
            $items = $xml->firstChild;     
            $item = $xml->createElement('item');   
            $items->appendChild($item); 
            $id = $xml->createElement('id');
            $itemdetail = $xml->createElement('itemdetail'); 
            $item->appendChild( $id );
            $id->nodeValue = $id;
            $item->appendChild( $itemdetail );
            $ItemDetail->nodeValue = $item_detail;


            $xml->save("item.xml");

           }
```

Comment: Do you want to store the *first* ten characters, or the *last* ten? Of do you want to save five characters less than the input? Can you provide examples of what you want to achieve? BTW, using POST requests, you should replace `%20` by `+` after encoding the string with `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use php [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$item_detail= substr($_POST["itd"], 0,10);
```

As a side note you should look into sanitising the $_POST data before.

EDIT

I have sorted out your variable names as you where overwriting the post vars with the xml vars

data.php

```
 <?php
$post_id= $_POST["idd"];
$post_item_detail = substr($_POST["itd"], 0,10);

$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->load("item.xml");

$xml->formatOutput = true;   

$items = $xml->documentElement;
$itemsLength = $items->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i = 0; $i < $itemsLength->length; $i++) {
$itm = $items->getElementsByTagName('item')->item($i);
$oldItem = $items->removeChild($itm);
}


$items = $xml->firstChild;     
$item = $xml->createElement('item');   
$items->appendChild($item); 
$id = $xml->createElement('id');
$itemdetail = $xml->createElement('itemdetail'); 
$item->appendChild( $id );
$id->nodeValue = $post_id;
$item->appendChild( $itemdetail );
$itemdetail->nodeValue = $post_item_detail;

$xml->save("item.xml");

?>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>

</doc>
```

Comment: i want to enter the first 10 characters of 'item_detail' into 'itemdetail'   element of xml file

Comment: @thomas , i tried with ur code but it gives an error  'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in data.php on line 2

Comment: yes its working.thanks for ur help. can u also provide code for deleting all elements from 'item.xml' file

Comment: I have added a method that removes all nodes labeled item.

Comment: but i want to delete all elements including root element also from xml file

Comment: If you wanted to replace 'item' with 'doc' or whatever you have labeled your root element as. But in doing so, unless you add a new root element you won't be able to add any more items.

Comment: yes i know but i am deleting all elements with root element to get filesize 0.

Comment: if i delete the file then file will not be existed.but i need that file exists but its filesize is zero thats y i want to delete all elements from xml file